# How to extract parameters attached to a URL in a script on the server related to get diagrams from Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set up a service on my web space that will receive parameters attached to a URL. Then extract them on the server in a script to replace default parameters by the received ones to generate charts.

I am just engaged with html, javascript, jquery and google charts for roundabout one week. Took some quick online tutorials on some aspects. So I am a novice. Please excuse errors in terminology!

Basically in a web browser the url will be entered with attached parameters. The script on the server receives the url, extracts the parameters and puts them at the places where default values are situated in the code. In the index.htm file is a code that defines properties of a Google Chart. The url parameters are the values of the columns. From that a request to Google Charts API is sent, which returns the generated graph, which is then visible in the browser window of the user.

I have made an example code for the diagram (see attached). Now I am searching for a simple method to do what I stated above. I already read about "param"," "get", "set" and have seen many example codes, with and without jquery, etc. Everybody does it in his own way and with various complexity. I tried to implement those methods into my code, but had a lot of errors I could not solve. 
Unfortunately it was not obvious to me for some code, where to put it exactly, as in the examples it was at a certain position, which did not work out for me (sorry that I have included more lines of code as usual people would do here to show you, but it is necessary for me to understand it).

Could you maybe help me, showing me in the example code I provided how I could do it for the three columns of the chart?

The url could look like that:
https://example.org/?c1=10&c2=12&c3=7

In the code the parameters have the same names c1, ..., for simplicity.
Additionally, image of code: https://imgur.com/ns1hL2P

Thank you for any help!
Kaydon

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartA"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartColumnChart);
function drawChartColumnChart(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['',''],['c1',1],['c2',2],['c3',3]
],false);
    var options = {"axisTitlesPosition":"out","width":"900","height":"500","focusTarget":"datum",
    "animation":{"easing":"linear"},"bars":"horizontal"};
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartA'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: It would be nice, if someone could present the lines necessary in the code for this simple case of three values that are used as parameters. With that I would probably understand the method and be able to create code for more complex cases of parameters received via url and more complex graphs. Thank you

Comment: do you want to get value of c1 c2 and c3 parameter in URL?

Comment: I want to replace the c1, c2, c3 values in the code by the values received in the url!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getParameterByName(name, url)` to extract parameters

```js
var url = 'https://example.org/?c1=10&c2=12&c3=7'
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var c1 = getParameterByName('c1', url);
console.log(c1);
// your function liket this
/*
function drawChartColumnChart(){
    var c1 = getParameterByName('c1', url);
    var c2 = getParameterByName('c2', url);
    var c3 = getParameterByName('c3', url);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['',''],['c1',c1],['c2',c2],['c3',c3];
],false);

*/
```

Comment: Ok, but does your method work for all URLs? Meaning, when queries arrive with different values for the parameters c1,c2,c3? As:https://example.org/?c1=2000&c2=1500&c3=35537'. Or only for the single case you have as 'var url = 'https://example.org/?c1=10&c2=12&c3=7'

Comment: Ah cool, that sounds nice, I will check, if it works this evening!

Comment: I did not get it right. Tried to use your code, but it just returns the diagram as before with the default values. Could you possibly put the code at the right place.